# Why does nchar return the wrong values for large numeric variables in R?

Tags: r, string, scientific-notation

From my understanding the input should be converted to character without specifying

"x = ...character vector, or a vector to be coerced to a character vector"

```
nchar(2015122514204000000)
# 18 
nchar("2015122514204000000")
# 19 

# Replacing the end zeroes with 111111
nchar(2015122514204111111)
# 19
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is doing the following:

```
as.character(2015122514204000000)
"2.015122514204e+18"
```

and

```
nchar("2.015122514204e+18")
```

is 18.

Try e.g. `options(scipen=999)` to prevent scientific notation, and `nchar(2015122514204000000)` will return `19`. Hope this helps!

Comment: If you don't want to mess with the R options you can also use a call to format, like so `nchar(format(2015122514204000000, scientific=F))`

Comment: That's useful to know, I was not aware of that parameter in format, thanks!

Comment: the other thing to point out is that it may be best to modify code upstream to make sure this value is never turned into a number in the first place, e.g. with the `colClasses` argument to `read.csv` ...

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what is happening:

```
> as.character(2015122514204000000)
[1] "2.015122514204e+18"
> nchar(as.character(2015122514204000000))
[1] 18
```